# Corner detection algorithm for mobile

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to find a good algorihtm that would detect corners in a image in a mobile phone. There are multiple algorithms to do that I am not sure which one will perform better in a memory and processor limited environment.

Specifically I am trying to find a sudoku grid in a picture taken using the camera of the phone. I am using C# and could not find any libraries that has basic image processing features. I implemented a Sobel filter to do edge detection and that is where I stand.

To make it clear the question is does anybody have any suggestions to use a specific algorithm or a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say "corner detection" by itself is a very good way to do this. Take a step back and think about a photo of a sodoku grid, there are probably lots of assumptions you can make to simplify things.

For example, a sodoku grid always looks exactly the same:

- White square
- 9 x 9 regular grid

[treating the image in the HSV colour space](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=68501) will allow you to look for high lightness areas (white-ish colours), RGB is a bit pants for most image-processing techniques.

[thresholding the image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) should then reduce noise

[Adjusting the image histogram](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/histgram.htm) first may also give you better results as it will probably whiten the grid (depends on the image though).

Then all you have to do is find a square. Because you know the grid is regular within it, you can divide the pixels up accordingly and OCR the squares with a number in.

:D

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used HSV but in a different way. I keep the dark areas assuming grid itself will be printed in black ink but your suggestion seems better. I probably also need to do a shear transformation before detecting squares. I took some test images in all of them grids are deformed and are trapeziums. Or maybe I can say that all disconnected white areas with certain sizes are grid.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for a regular 9x9 grid consider the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).  One way is to run an edge detector first, find all straight lines using the original Hough transform, and then try to figure out which of them form a grid.  Or maybe you can come up with a clever way to parametrize the whole grid.

Comment: I thought about Hough transform but I was concerned about the complexity. I was thinking of finding points where vertical edges and horizontal edges intersects. But it also fails, when there is angled line. Maybe I can use Hough transform to first remove these kind of lines. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I think that finding corners is a good strategy.  There are many corner detection operators.  Harris operator is a popular one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection

Comment: Hough transform is really fast and easy to implement. Then one may cycle through detected lines, calculate their lenghts and search for ones, that intersect more than, say, 6-7 other lines.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) to be very useful in processing images, and I would score myself as a pretty average programmer.

[Here's an example](http://www.moosechips.com/2008/08/opencv-corner-detection-using-cvgoodfeaturestotrack/) (in C++, but you could probably port it) that does corner detection in OpenCV.

Comment: Hi Chris, I used OpenCV before but I am not aware of any port of it that would run in a mobile phone. Do you know any such thing? Maybe I can quickly play with it and try to compile it using windows mobile sdk. Thanks.